# enable_shared_from_this. Why the crash?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Could someone explain why the following crashes?  I'm using enable_shared_from_this so that bob does not get deleted.

```
class Person : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Person> {
    private:
        std::string name;
    public:
        Person (const std::string& name) : name(name) {}
        std::string getName() const {return name;}
        void introduce() const;
};

void displayName (std::shared_ptr<const Person> person) {
    std::cout << "Name is " << person->getName() << "." << std::endl;
}

void Person::introduce() const {
    displayName (this->shared_from_this());
}

int main() {
    Person* bob = new Person ("Bob");
    bob->introduce();  // Crash here.  Why?
}
```

Comment: "Before calling `shared_from_this`, there should be at least one `std::shared_ptr<T> p` that owns `*this`." - [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this)

Comment: @clcto, I think your comment deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) states:

> Before calling `shared_from_this`, there should be at least one `std::shared_ptr<T> p` that owns `*this`.

So if we change `main()` to:

```
std::shared_ptr<Person> bob( new Person ("Bob") );
bob->introduce();
```

there will be no issue since there is already a `shared_ptr` that owns `*this`

Comment: Or better yet: 
`std::shared_ptr<Person> bob = std::make_shared<Person>("Bob");`

Answer (score 7):

One of the preconditions of `shared_from_this` is that the object (`this`) has to be already owned by some `shared_ptr`. It then returns a `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with the already existing `shared_ptr`.

Because your object is not owned by any `shared_ptr` when calling `shared_from_this`, you are invoking undefined behaviour (it crashes).

Try this instead:

```
int main() {
    auto bob = std::make_shared<Person>("Bob");
    bob->introduce();
}
```